# Equation not completely on the left with flalign

Tags: equations, amsmath

I use the following code to place the equation in the left. But as you can see, it not completely on the left side while the number (1) is on the right side of the column.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
This is the text. This is the text. This is the text. This is the text. This is the text. 
\begin{flalign}
    \label{c}
    C = \frac{X}{Y}
\end{flalign}
This is the text. This is the text. This is the text. This is the text. This is the text.   
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}% ADDED
\begin{document}
This is the text. This is the text. This is the text. This is the text. This is the text. 
\begin{flalign}
    \label{c}
    C = \frac{X}{Y}
\end{flalign}
This is the text. This is the text. This is the text. This is the text. This is the text.   
\end{document}
```